# Display Recently Updated Posts Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Floating around the Internet is a piece of PHP code that is designed to display recently updated posts/pages in WordPress. After submitting a request to experts-exchange for assistance, within moments, I had the raw code I needed.

However, the original PHP code still didn't work for my WordPress installation. After some tweaks and a lot of additional bells and whistles, I had managed to piece together the code needed to only display recently updated posts.

**At this point I ask for help to show only posts from a specific category. Is it possible to show only posts from a specific category? Can you help?**

this is the current code:

```
<div class="statistics">
<?php
$today = current_time('mysql', 1);
$howMany = 10; //Number of posts you want to display
if ($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts    WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_name NOT LIKE  '%revision%' AND post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $howMany")) :
?>
<h2><?php _e('ULTIME SERIE TV AGGIORNATE'); ?></h2>         
<ul>
<?php
foreach($recentposts as $post) {
if ($post->post_title == '') {
$post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post->ID);
}
/* If no post title exists one will be assigned to it. */
echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
echo mysql2date('d/m/Y', $post->post_modified); 
echo "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
echo $post->post_title;
echo '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The table are the categories stored in **wp_term_taxonomy** and which method is used to store items under a specific category database and its **ID** (**term_taxonomy_id**) This is a picture:

[TABLE picture](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/2961/immagine3kxn.png)

In a plugin ([recently-updated-posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recently-updated-posts/)) I found this function but I do not know how to put it in my code...

```
if ($options['excludeCategory']) {
$select .= ", GROUP_CONCAT(`tt`.`term_id`) AS `terms`";
$from   .= " LEFT JOIN `{$wpdb->term_relationships}` AS `tr` ON `tr`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`"
                     . " LEFT JOIN `{$wpdb->term_taxonomy}` AS `tt` ON `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id` =   `tr`.`term_taxonomy_id`";
 $where  .= " AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'"
 . " AND `tt`.`term_id` NOT IN ({$options['excludeCategory']})";
 $group  = "GROUP BY `ID`";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) and pass in the arguments for category.

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'category' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $post ){
if ($post["post_title"] == '') {
$post["post_title"] = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post["ID"]);
}
?>
<li><a href='<?php echo get_permalink($post["ID"]) ?>'>
<?php echo mysql2date('d/m/Y', $post["post_modified"])?>
&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<?php echo $post["post_title"]?>
</a></li>
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /home/stream/public_html/wp-content/themes/mythemes/footer.php on line 68

Comment: Assuming this is after the `ul`, did you remove the `endif`?

Comment: endif will be removed, but there is a syntax error. ERROR IMAGE: http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9270/updatepost.png

Comment: this should be your code
`<div class="statistics">
 <h2><?php _e('ULTIME REVISIONI'); ?></h2>
 <ul>
 <?php 
 $args = array('category' => '5');
 $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
 foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
  if ($post["post_title"] == ''){
   $post["post_title"] = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post["ID"]);
  }
  ?>
  <li><a href='<?php echo get_permalink($post["ID"]) ?>'>
  <?php echo mysql2date('d/m/Y', $post["post_modified"]) ?>
  &nbsp;-&nbsp;
  <?php echo $post["post_title"] ?>
  </a></li>
  <?php 
 }
  ?>
 </ul>
</div>`

Comment: think it is possible to order the posts by date? with ORDER DESC ?

Comment: you can use [these parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) within your $args to specify the order.

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
<div class="update">
<?php
$today = current_time('mysql', 1);
if ($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts    WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_name NOT LIKE  '%revision%' AND post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt")) :
?>
<h2><?php _e('GLI ULTIMI EPISODI AGGIUNTI'); ?></h2>        
<ul>
<?php $args = array('category' => '30', 'orderby'  => 'modified', 'post_status' => 'publish',   'posts_per_page' => 11);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
if ($post["post_title"] == ''){ $post["post_title"] = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post["ID"]);
}
?>
<li><?php echo mysql2date('d/m/Y', $post["post_modified"]) ?>
&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<a href='<?php echo get_permalink($post["ID"]) ?>'>
<?php echo $post["post_title"] ?>
</a></li> <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: In your opinion is all the code necessary to start or should I fix it? <?php
$today = current_time('mysql', 1);
if ($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts    WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_name NOT LIKE  '%revision%' AND post_name NOT LIKE '%autosave%' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt")) :
?>

Answer (score 0):

This code is another way of getting the recently updated posts and pages.

```
<?php 

$today  = current_time('mysql', 1);
$number = 5; // number of posts

if($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $number")):

?>

<h2><?php _e("Recently Updated"); ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php

foreach($recentposts as $post) {

    if($post->post_title == '') $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post->ID);
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';

} ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```